# reading and running function calls from raw_input

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to read function calls and values from raw_input and run them on a list. i've made a list that i'm calling the functions on, and a list to hold the raw_input. My issue is getting the function calls from the list called cmd to be called on the original list, called 'l'. for instance, if the value of cmd[0] is 'append', and the value of cmd[1:] is [6,7,8], i want to call 'l.append(6,7,8)'.

this is where i keep getting the error, on the % string stuff.
print(l.'%s(%s)' % (cmd[0], cmd[1:]))

Comment: here is the section i'm working on:                                                            'n = int(raw_input())

l = []

for i in range(1,n+1):
    cmd = raw_input().split(' ')
    print(l.'%s(%s)' % (cmd[0], cmd[1:])) '

Comment: Which version of Python do you use? `raw_input()` is Python 2.x syntax but on the other hand `print()` indicates Python 3.x

Comment: python3, that should be just input(), i think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just printing out the function to STDOUT does not call it. Consider using Pythons built-in function [`exec()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) which supports dynamic execution of Python code.

To use `exec()` just pass a string to it, which is parsed as a suite of Python statements which is then executed. Your string consists of an object `l`, a method `append()` which is stored in `cmd[0]` and the methods arguments `args` held in `cmd[1:]`:

```
exec("{object}.{method}({args})".format(object="l", method=cmd[0], args=cmd[1:]))
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: it's already a big help and i haven't solved the problem yet. at least i know where to go! i'm trying to use python3, but i keep slipping in remnants of 2.

Comment: Ok, If you want you can except this answer if it was helpful for you. :)

Comment: okay, just did. i appreciate your help, i'm kind of a noob at this.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks for your help.